# Post request body is empty on server side Meteor (Error 503)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, axios

Im sending data to an API endpoint using Axios. On `Network` side in the console, request body has the correct data. On the `Meteor` server side, both params and body are empty and throws a 503 error on console.

I read a similar questions and made sure `content-type` is set to `application\json`, I tried setting `mode` to `no-cors`, I am calling a local endpoint.

Client-Side code

```
const modifyPackage = () => {

            const requestContent = {
                "filePath": package.file.path,
                "data": data
            };
            const requestConfig = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }

            axios.post('/modifyPackage',requestContent,requestConfig)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch ((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }   
        modifyPackage();
```

Server-Side code

```
  Picker.middleware( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) );
  Picker.middleware( bodyParser.json() );

  Picker.route('/modifyPackage',(params, req,res,next) => {
    console.dir("## BODY ##");
    console.dir(req.body);
    if (req.method == "POST") {
      const modifiedContent = req.body.data;
      const pathString = req.body.filePath;
      console.dir(pathString);
      console.dir(modifiedContent);

      fs.writeFile(pathString, modifiedContent, (err,data) => {
        if (data) {
          console.dir(data);
        }
        res.end();
      });
    } else {
      console.dir("Not Post")
      res.end("No Response");
    }
  });
```

Comment: If `params` is empty as you say, you then cannot access properties on it as in: `const modifiedContent = params.body.data;`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't `params` refer to path parameters? Ie `/path/:param1/:param2`. Also, you definitely don't want to use `no-cors` mode

Comment: @Chase @Phil yes, you are both right. Params arent suppose to contain any data. Im just printing everything possible. The issue is `req.body` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

503 error Server side error

```
const modifiedContent = req.body.data;
const pathString = req.body.filePath;
```

Comment: this returns an `undefined` error because req.body is empty

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Picker. You can use built-in Meteor Webapp package.

```
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import connectRoute from 'connect-route';

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(connectRoute((router) => {
  router.post('/modifyPackage/:someParam/:otherParam', (req, res, next) => {
    // some logic here.

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('some data');
  });
}));
```

Comment: Ive had some issues with WebApp, its not about what middleware to use.